# What boolean algebra simplication is this when applying Shannon's expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Found this [questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590201/when-do-we-apply-shannon-s-expansion-or-what-is-the-motivation-using-shannon-s-e) about Shannon's expression. While I am trying to follow its logic, found one Super convenience simplification used.
Can we do this in general while dealing with boolean algebra? or only in Shannon's expression ?

Can we just turn b+d into 1 while we have (+)⋅1 previously in the equation ?

also  + into 1 while  we have (+)⋅1  previously in the equation ?

Picture from that question:

[image]

My questions is
see how  + part turned into 1 in ( ++++ ).
and how  +  part turned into 1 in ( ++++ ). is that just because 1⋅ (+ ) and 1⋅ (+ ) respectively ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a + b + d)(a' + b + c) = aa' + ab + ac + ba` + bb + bc + da' + db + dc

= 0 + ab + ac + ba` + b + bc + da' + db + dc

= b (a + a' + 1 + c + d) + ac + a'd

= b + ac + a'd

= b (a + a') + ac + a'd

= a (b + c) + a' (b + d)

So applied to last term in two components:

a (b + c) (b + c + d + e + f) = 1 (b + c) (b + c + d + e + f)

= (bb + bc + bd + be + bf) + (cb + cc + cd + ce + cf)

= b + c

**= a (b + c)**

*Other terms disapper due to absorption law.* \$X (X + Y) =  X\$

Alternatively: \$X (1 + Y) =  X\$

*X and Y can be one or more terms.*

Similarly
a' (b + d) (b + c + d + e + f) = 1 (b + d) (b + c + d + e + f)

**= a' (b + d)**

So yes simplification applies to boolean algebra.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question or I just didn't make my question clear. 
You see how  + part turned into 1 in ( ++++ ). 
and how  +  part turned into 1 in ( ++++ ). is that just because 1⋅ (+ ) and 1⋅ (+ ) respectively

Comment: So, we can always do this because of absorption ? like 

 (1,,,,,) =1⋅ (++f) ⋅( ++++ )= (++f)( 1++e )=(++f)
The" magic" step is just turn whatever  1⋅ (++f) part into 1 in the following part?

Comment: There are 2 things in play.  One true when a = 1 and one true when a' = 1. (b + d) (b + c + d + e + f) = (b + d) (b + d + c + e + f) = (b + d) (1 + c + e + f) = (b + d).  It is absorption.

Comment: Yes.  Replace b + c + f with X.

Comment: What if F(A,B,C,D,E)=(A+B+D)(A’+B+C)(B+C+D+E), then we apply Shannon to B, which became F(A,0,C,D,E) =1  when B is 0. 
This is not closely related to this question, but still is about Shannon. If you don't mind answering.

Comment: You may be confusing, the use of a' being 1 when a = 0.  If b = 0, the expression is false.  Read my full answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130461/discussion-between-maxfield-and-stainlesssteelrat).